# Ionic: How to activate default splash screen?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I am making an app, that to initialize everything it takes about a second. So it became clear that the best solution is to display a splash screen.

I am now making a blank app from scratch to test it.

**THE STEPS:**

For now i have done the following steps:

1. Create a blank app.
2. Added platform android and ios.
3. Running ionic resources (i suspect there is no need of this if have added platforms, but i am not sure)
4. Check that into the resource folder properly appear icon.png and splash.png
5. Check config.xml and see that there are the following settings:

   ```
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>  
   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
   ```
6. Install ngCordova and include it in index.html and as a dependency

   ```
   <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

   angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])
   ```

It is supposed to work i guess. But i don't see any splash screen in my app.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i activate the splash screen?
I mean how can i actually see it appearing in the main page?

(for test purpose that ionic default image is fine and 3 seconds is okay)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok basically it is allright. The problem was just in testing the app (my bad). I was making quick tests in the browser (localhost) and by using [quirktools.com/screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

But in order to see the splashscreen in action i had to test the app directly in the phone or with emulators like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/).

There the splashscreen is working properly.
No plugin needed. Basically just following that steps is enough (even without running ionic resources).

Answer (score 2):

You should add [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) to your plugins, then your settings in `config.xml`
 will work.

Comment: Is that the only possibility? There is no way to just display that default splash screen?

Comment: You can display the default splash screen with this plugin.

Comment: No, you have to install the plugin. See my answer from another question for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387969/cordova-5-1-1-splashscreen-not-working/31470021#31470021

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've read the instructions OK, but what you're missing is the `ionic resources` command. Take a look at the [here for more info](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/create-icons-and-splash-screen-automatically-with-ionic-resources/) but basically you just have to run the aforementioned `ionic resources` command from the root project directory after you made the necessary .psd of .png files and placed them in the `resources` folder.

Comment: Ah ok i see. That command automatically generate icons and splash screen. But as i can see there is already a splash.png and icon into resource folder. I just would like to actually display it in my app.

Comment: Then just run `ionic resources` with that image in `resource` folder, and ionic cli will set up everything for you, no need to do it manually.

Comment: Done it. but nothing changed. I suppose that adding platform android and ios automatically add the same resources. But my question is about how to actually display that in the app.

Comment: Try to recreate a test project with `ionic start appName blank`. Then add the platforms which you want (`ionic platform add ios`, `ionic platform add android`). Then make the `resources` folder in the root directory and put the splash screen image in there. Run `ionic resources` command. Build the app with `ionic build ios` or `ionic build android` and run it on your device with `ionic run ios` or `ionic run android`. This should work as expected now.